# how to find a plane equation in python

Tags: python, math, geometry

The information I currently have is the four vertex coordinates of a plane (three-dimensional space). A(X, Y, Z), B(X, Y, Z), C(X, Y, Z), D(X, Y, Z)
I would like to use this information to find the equation of the plane.

I found the normal vector of the plane, but I couldn't find the equation of the plane because I didn't know the coordinate of one point on the plane.I'd appreciate it if you could tell me how

Comment: check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-sympy-plane-equation-method/ if you want to use a library for computing the plane equation.

Comment: A, B, C, D should be on the plane, is it? Then you have the normal vector and one point on the plane to get the equation?

Answer (score 1):

To get canonical plane equation, we need three non-collinear points in the plane.

At first calculate normal vector using vector product of AB and AC vectors (you already know how to make it). So you have got three components `(nx, ny, nz)` - they are coefficients of plane equation, but the last coefficient is not known yet:

```
nx*x + ny*y + nz*z + d = 0
```

Now we can substitute any point (say A) coordinates into the plane equation to get the last coefficient. (Note that if you need any point in the plane - you already have it!)

```
nx*ax + ny*ay + nz*az + d = 0
d = -(nx*ax + ny*ay + nz*az)
```

That's all

```
def calc_plane(ax, ay, az, bx, by, bz, cx, cy, cz):
    abx = bx - ax
    aby = by - ay
    abz = bz - az
    acx = cx - ax
    acy = cy - ay
    acz = cz - az
    nx = aby * acz - abz * acy
    ny = abz * acx - abx * acz
    nz = abx * acy - aby * acx
    if nx==0 and ny==0 and nz==0:
        return None                 #collinear points case
    return (nx, ny, nz, -nx*ax-ny*ay-nz*az)

print(calc_plane(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1))
print(calc_plane(1,-2,1,4,-2,-2,4,1,4))

(1, 1, 1, -1)
(9, -18, 9, -54)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [`scikit-spatial`](https://scikit-spatial.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) library to get the equation of a plane. If you have three non-collinear points, you can use the following code:

```py
from skspatial.objects import Plane
plane = Plane.from_points([0, 0, 3], [1, 0, -4], [3, 3, -5])
```

The library can be installed using pip: `pip install scikit-spatial`